# Using ssh key-type ed25519 as standard type when generating a new key?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen, ssh-config

Is it possible to set key-type ed25519 as default in /etc/ssh/config or .ssh/config for `ssh-keygen`, so that it generates these key-types as a default?

I looked at `man ssh-keygen` and the documentation of `ssh-config`, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

There is no configuration option for this.

Taking a look at the source code for `ssh-keygen` reveals that `-t` [assigns a value](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6452f89577ec4f22440c31b8e19b061d1a7c4b2a/ssh-keygen.c#L3505-L3507) to `key_type_name`, which if omitted is [assigned](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6452f89577ec4f22440c31b8e19b061d1a7c4b2a/ssh-keygen.c#L3791-L3792) the value of `DEFAULT_KEY_TYPE_NAME`. That one is [defined conditionally](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6452f89577ec4f22440c31b8e19b061d1a7c4b2a/ssh-keygen.c#L70-L74) as `"rsa"` if `WITH_OPENSSL` is defined, and as `"ed25519"` otherwise.

Since OpenSSH is built with OpenSSL on nearly all distributions, the default is `rsa`. To change the default, you'd need to build OpenSSH from source and change the default before compiling.

(Using `./configure --without-openssl` would also work, but this is [marked](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6452f89577ec4f22440c31b8e19b061d1a7c4b2a/configure.ac#L135) as experimental and only gives you a limited subset of crypto algorithms.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set key-type ed25519 as default in `/etc/ssh/config` or `.ssh/config` for ssh-keygen, so that it generates these key-types as a default?

You won't have to do anything... beside upgrading openSSH.

[OpenSSH 9.5](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) (2023-10-04) includes [`ssh-keygen(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1) which **now generates Ed25519 keys by default**.

> Ed25519 public keys are very convenient due to their small size. Ed25519 keys are specified in RFC 8709 and OpenSSH has supported them since version 6.5 (January 2014).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by putting this in your .ssh/config:

IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Comment: This defines the identity file, that is used for `ssh` itself. I‘m looking for an option for `ssh-keygen`. I‘ll clarify my question.